# Text editor with exclusive mode

Tags: windows, text-editors

Is there text editor that can open file in exclusive mode? Its a standard way how to restrict access to file to one process / user in operating system Windows. I need this because of editing file stored on network drive. This file can be edited by other two people on domain. File editor I am using at this time (Notepad++) doesnt support this.

Comment: Sorry, are you saying you want it to be editable by multiple people or just one?

Comment: Multiple people but one at a time to prevent conflicts.

Comment: Have you considered using version control software (svn, hg, git, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, this is a viable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Dreamweaver - it has a check in check out feature designed for this (or [TFS for Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) but this is more expensive I think). However, you ARE given the right to overwrite some one else which may be a deal breaker.

More details with Dreamweaver: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7ebfa.html and describes itself as:

> If you’re working in a collaborative environment, you can check files
>   in and out from local and remote servers. If you’re the only person
>   working on the remote server, you can use the Put and Get commands
>   without checking files in or out.
>
> Checking out a file is the equivalent of declaring “I’m working on
>   this file now—don’t touch it!” When a file is checked out, the name of
>   the person who checked out the file is displayed in the Files panel,
>   along with a red check mark (if a team member checked out the file) or
>   green check mark (if you checked out the file) next to the file’s
>   icon.
>
> Checking in a file makes the file available for other team members to
>   check out and edit. When you check in a file after editing it, your
>   local version becomes read-only and a lock symbol appears beside the
>   file in the Files panel to prevent you from making changes to the
>   file.
>
> Dreamweaver does not make checked-out files read-only on the remote
>   server. If you transfer files with an application other than
>   Dreamweaver, you can overwrite checked-out files. However, in
>   applications other than Dreamweaver, the LCK file is visible next to
>   the checked-out file in the file hierarchy to help prevent such
>   accidents.

Comment: Ouch.  I hope there's a better solution. Dreamweaver last time I checked (10 years ago but probably still applies) is a big program with lots of panes, and options, for professionals to write HTML cleanly, so has lots of features for writing webpages. I doubt you can really call Dreamweaver a text editor.  MS Word may also lock a file, but it's not what one would call a text editor either.